# I'm trying to have a default message for g:select

Tags: select, grails, gsp

I have a select statement an im trying to get the drop down select menu to display a prompt line like Please Select instead of just a default selection.

```
<g:select name="country" from="${countrylist}" />
```

Is there a way to do this with the value attribute or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the noSelection attribute of the g:select tag. [Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Tags/select.html).

```
<g:select name="country" from="${countrylist}" noSelection="['':'Please select a country']" />
```